# headers/ tags are not displaying when an xml is exported to excel using VBA Macro

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I am using the below code to export the xml to excel.

```
Sub ImportXMLtoList()  

    Dim strTargetFile As String  
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    strTargetFile = "C:\XML_Demo\demo.xml"  
    Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True  

End Sub
```

While this code is executed, xml values are being displayed in spreadsheet, but not the corresponding tags. "demo.xml" is a dummy xml I have put here, as I work on client data, I cannot share the actual xml which has this problem. The same code works for other xmls. 
Please let me know what would be the issue.

Comment: Have you tried the Workbook.XmlImport method?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:=strTargetFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadOpenXml`